# smartGWT grid not showing summary (need to load all records?)

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

i have a grid where i need to show the sum of a column at the end of the grid. I use the function

```
myListGrid.setShowGridSummary(true);
```

if the grid contains 60 records it will do the summary without problems, if it goes >61 the summary will show no data at all. I believe this problem is caused by the grid paging (not loading all the data at once). Is there a possible workaround for this or maybe a function to load all the data that i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myListGrid.setShowAllRecords(true)
```

Drawing all rows causes longer initial rendering time, but allows smoother vertical scrolling. With a very large number of rows, `showAllRows` will become too slow.